# How to create dynamic nested routes in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How do I use routing and folder structure to pass multiple optional parameters in the URL?
What folder structure should I create to handle such cases where the route is something like

```
user/:id/:product
user/:id/product/:id
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create dynamic nested routes. In order to do that you need to manage your folders as indicated in the documentation [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-nested-routes).

For your example it should be :

```
// For user/:id/:product
user/_id/_product 
pages/
--| user/
-----| _id/
--------| index.vue
--------| _product
-----------| index.vue


// For user/:id/product/:id
pages/
--| user/
-----| _id/
--------| index.vue
--------| product
-----------| _id.vue
```

Comment: I am still learning this, but where is the parent file for the nested children files?  Per the Nuxt documentation, there needs to be a .vue file with the same name as the directory holding the children files, e.g. user/_id.vue and user/_id/product.vue